# R ggscatter p-Value rounding?

Tags: r, p-value, ggpubr

Dea(R)-Friends

I am currently using R for drawing accelerometer-derived data using ggscatter. As the data is highly correlated, the plotted p-value is rounded to 1 which, scientifically is a bit.... lets call it weird. As I looked into the arguments that I can pass to ggscatter and not found anything useful I am asking for help. How can I determine how ggscatter displays the p-value in terms of numbers of decimals.

My source looks like:

```
ggscatter(data, x = "Nexus1", y = "Nexus2",add = "reg.line", 
          conf.int = TRUE, cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson", 
          xlab = "Nexus 1 [m/s^2]", ylab = "Nexus 2 [m/s^2]")
```

Any hint is highly appreciated!
- Claudio

Comment: Correlation is not associated with p-values, that is high correlation does not mean high p-value, not necessarily.

Comment: that was not my question ;)